# Añadir una fuente a header.tpl

Tags: css3, prestashop

Estoy tratando de insertar un tipo de fuente a la factura de Prestashop, la fuente en cuestión está incluida ya en el header de la tienda, y funciona perfectamente ya que se utiliza en varios elementos.
En cambio si se llama a la font-family desde el archivo de factura header.tpl no surte ningún efecto.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando un navegador hace un request al servidor web, este le devuelve como respuesta un codigo HTML, posteriormente el navegador carga asincronicamente todos los enlaces externos que estan contenido en el HTML (digase imagenes, css, js, fuentes, etc).

En la generacion de PDF en Prestashop funciona de la siguiente manera:
- A partir de un TPL se genera un HTML.
- Este HTML en forma de string se le pasa a una libreria para generacion del PDF.

Como podras ver el paso de cargar todos los enlaces externos no ocurre en la generacion de PDF porque no hay un navegador web de por medio.

Por tanto, para incluir una fuente externa asumo que habra 2 variantes posibles (no he probado ninguna antes):
- Incrustar la fuente completa en el TPL de forma que cuando se genere el HTML ya esta contenida.
- LLamar a una funcion que tienen las clases de generacion de PDF de Prestashop y que permite agregar una fuente especifica.

Creo que la ultima opcion seria lo mas viable y con mas posibilidades de exito.

Suerte y por favor, actualizanos si tienes exito.